# Why the event doesn't get triggered?

Tags: jquery, html

I am using [graphdracula](http://www.graphdracula.net/showcase/) to draw a graph.  Graph is dynamically created upon an event.

[image]

The above snapshot shows the `svg` added dynamically inside the `div` tag. Each ellipse created has an `id`.

I am trying to bind id `player-1` and `player-2` with an event.

```
$('#player-1').mouseover(function(event) {
                var parentOffset = $(this).offset();
                x1 = event.pageX - parentOffset.left;
                y1 = event.pageY - parentOffset.top;
                console.log("For player-1 : " + x1 + ',' + y1);
            });

            $('#player-2').mouseover(function(event) {
                var parentOffset = $(this).offset();
                x1 = event.pageX - parentOffset.left;
                y1 = event.pageY - parentOffset.top;
                console.log("For player-2 : " + x1 + ',' + y1);
            });
```

But the event doesn't get triggered. What could be the reason for this? I have checked with `click` event but it doesn't get triggered. What could be the reason for this?

Following snippet, adds a graph to the document:

```
$('#cont').click(function(event) { 
                var width = $('#cont').width() - 1;
                var height = $('#cont').height() - 1;
                g = new Graph();
                g.addNode("player-1");
                g.addNode("player-2");
                //g.addNode("player-2");
                g.addEdge("player-1", "player-2",  {"directed":true});
                var layouter = new Graph.Layout.Spring(g);

                 /* draw the graph using the RaphaelJS draw implementation */
                var renderer = new Graph.Renderer.Raphael('cont', g, width, height);

                var redraw = function() {
                    layouter.layout();
                    renderer.draw();
                };
                hide = function(id) {
                    g.nodes[id].hide();
                };
                show = function(id) {
                    g.nodes[id].show();
                };
 });
```

Comment: how/when is the svg inserted? is the jquery even binding done after the svg is in the dom?

Comment: You may need to delegate the event.

Comment: Try to change listener with 'on' jquery (https://api.jquery.com/on/) like this `$(document).on("click","player-1"` to allow listener on Dom element generate after declaration

Comment: And a jsfiddle can be helpful

Comment: @atmd svg is inserted upon the `$('#cont').click` event I have mentioned above.

Comment: Try the `.on` method of jQuery, i.e. `$('#cont').on('click',function(event) {...} ` since that has the ability to **handle events on descendants not yet created/added**.

Comment: Are the mouse events on the svg bound before or after the svg are inserted?

Comment: @Huangism after the svg is created

Comment: @SuhailGupta but in the code provided there isn't event binding in the svg creation block.

Comment: As @BlindingLight notes, `SVG` will not work with delegated event handlers :( You need to connect after they are added.

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie How do I do that? Why did you delete your answer?

Comment: I deleted it because it was incorrect. It would not have worked with SVG elements. `BlindingLight` feels their answer, below, is sufficient for you, so you might want to ask them instead :)

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie It worked actually, but now the coordinates captured were incorrect.

Comment: @Suhail Gupta: It worked with the delegated event handler??? things must have changed. I undeleted answer. Can you mockup a JSFiddle to check out the coordindate problem?

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie Yes,it is working fine.

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie It is strange. Does not work for `click` event.

Comment: If you *can* provide a JSFiddle to fix any remaining issues, that would be great.

Comment: Plz check my answer. However in my solution, every click on #cont will add a new event listener.

Answer (score 0):

It's better to use `on()` and `off()` because this way you can avoid multiple event handler registrations, see https://api.jquery.com/on/ and https://api.jquery.com/off/

Unfortunately I found this: "Note: Delegated events do not work for SVG."
So basically you have to register your event handlers after SVG is added to the DOM.

Comment: As of jQuery 1.7, the .live() method is deprecated.

Comment: Could you give a snippet in your answer

Comment: Just use .on('mouseover', function() {...}) instead of .mouseover(function() {...}) after you added player elements to the DOM. As I quoted delegated events won't work, so it's the order that important here: first add DOM elements, then register your event handlers (place your 1st snippet after ```g.addEdge("player-1", "player-2",  {"directed":true});```, you may have to put your 1st snippet in a setTimeout function to handle DOM insert delay, try it. I hope it's clear what I'm talking about, if not, please let me know. :)) I won't give you a snippet, because you won't learn it that way. ;)

Comment: can we discuss here at http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74183/migrated-from-http-stackoverflow-com-questions-29348270-why-the-event-doesnt-ge

Answer (score 0):

If your players are added dynamically, you may need to use delegated event handlers, attached to a *non-changing ancestor* element:

```
$('#cont').on("mouseover", '#player-1', function(event) {
            var parentOffset = $(this).offset();
            x1 = event.pageX - parentOffset.left;
            y1 = event.pageY - parentOffset.top;
            console.log("For player-1 : " + x1 + ',' + y1);
        });

$('#cont').on("mouseover", '#player-2', function(event) {
            var parentOffset = $(this).offset();
            x1 = event.pageX - parentOffset.left;
            y1 = event.pageY - parentOffset.top;
            console.log("For player-2 : " + x1 + ',' + y1);
        });
```

This assume `id="cont"` is a permanent element (seems to be in your code). This will then listen for the event (mouseover) to bubble up to the ancestor, *then* apply the jQuery selector, *then* apply the function to the matching element(s) that caused the event.

The upshot is they will respond for elements that only exist at event time (and not just event registration time).

Answer (score -1):

initializing second function (event listener) inside first function:

```
$('#cont').click(function(event) { 
    //current code is here 
    //then trigger second function:
     secondFunction()
 });
```

Second Function:

```
function secondFunction(){
 $('#player-1').on("mouseenter",function(event) {
  var parentOffset = $(this).offset();
  x1 = event.pageX - parentOffset.left;
  y1 = event.pageY - parentOffset.top;
  console.log("For player-1 : " + x1 + ',' + y1);
 });

 $('#player-2').on("mouseenter",function(event) {
   var parentOffset = $(this).offset();
   x1 = event.pageX - parentOffset.left;
   y1 = event.pageY - parentOffset.top;
   console.log("For player-2 : " + x1 + ',' + y1);
   });
}
```

Comment: You have mistakenly used the *non-delegated* syntax of `on`. This is not different  to using `.mouseover()`

Comment: Do you mean mouseenter instead?

Comment: No (that was a typo). I mean you have the wrong syntax completely for delegated events. You needed `$('#cont').on("mouseenter", '#player-1', function(event) {` instead.

Comment: what if call second function after first function. Check the edited answer.

Comment: Attaching an event handler, *inside an event handler* is usually a *really bad idea*. You keep accumulating multiple event handlers every time you click inside the `cont` div.